# How to use account and password to get a access_token from the server

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Now, we have a meeting room reservation web system. 
When the meeting room reservation is leave,
meeting room participants may be able to cancel the meeting.
But as the meeting room participants haven't cancel authority. 
We cannot put the meeting room management user information released to all users. 
So, we need to get the access_token to cancel the meeting on our server use to meeting manager account and password. 
Would you please tell me how to get to access_token from web server use to meeting manager account and password.

Comment: Although there is a ROPC flow in OAuth 2.0, but I don't recommend you use this flow.

Comment: You should normally not need to store passwords, it is very much against what apps normally do. I encourage you read the documentation and try to understand how the flows work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

About how to get access token of SharePoint online/O365, We can refer to the article below:

[SHAREPOINT ONLINE REMOTE AUTHENTICATION (AND DOC UPLOAD)](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/)